# Is past time for the [gettime] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I just saw a recent question with the [gettime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gettime) tag. It seems to be used for questions about getting the time on a system, but it seems kind of redundant given that we have [time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time) and [date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date) tags. It only has ~100 questions and no description.

I don't think it's useful, however it's not doing any harm. Would it be correct to delete it?

Comment: A quick google search for "gettime" reveals it's the name for a javscript function.  So it's way too specific to be a good tag.  I'm for burninating it.

Comment: I assume you meant to make this a burnination request. Feel free to roll back if you don't like those changes

Answer (score -1):

No, let's not burninate it.

[gettime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gettime) tag is about the `getTime()` function in JavaScript which is used to get the current time. It doesn't seem useless to me. Here are the reasons (from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191)):

> 1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**

Yes it *does* describe the contents of the question it is applied. A question which is tagged [gettime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gettime) **must** be about the `getTime()` function in JavaScript. However, seems like only ~50 are related to JavaScript...

> 2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Of course! The topic is related to functions, something which is programming-related, thus the questions are on-topic on Stack Overflow.

> 3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

Hmmmm... Well, yeah. It just adds that the question is related to the `getTime()` function. So, if someone wants to check questions about `getTime`, they will just search questions tagged [gettime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gettime).

> 4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Yes, it will *always* be a... function in JavaScript.

However, I would like to underline an important thing here. There are some questions (about 50-60) that **aren't related to JavaScript (`getTime` function)!**. So, two things are possible here:

- The questions that are about methods of getting time in different languages should be retagged (maybe be tagged with [time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time) or whatever is appropriate). In other words, a cleanup can be done
- The tag wiki (thus the whole tag meaning) may be changed to all methods of getting time in different languages. (However, I don't want to support this, as one of the burnination criteria will be valid.)

That said, the tag *should* **not** be removed, instead a cleanup can be done, so that the meaning of the tag will be the same in all common contexts.

*Note: the burnination request is a bit old; maybe the tag description and/or the tag wiki didn't exist, so the tag was a little bit ambiguous*

Comment: A whole tag just for a js function? Are you sure that's enough as a reason to not burninate it?

Comment: @window.document does it violate any of burnination criteria? No, nor it is denied to have too specific tags. There are tags about commands in git (i.e. [tag:git-reset] for `git reset`, etc.). This is a quite special case IMO, where the function is used to do something special, to get time.

Comment: Comparison to `git reset` is irrelevant here as it is a command and can be used in many ways and with other attributes. JavaScript's `getTime` function does the same thing (it returns the current time) and will do so in the future. It doesn't need its own tag.

Comment: @window.document 'the tag is too specific' is not a burnination reason itself.